# Adjective for the noun "scraps" in this context

Tags: word-request, spoken-english

> Leftover food is called **scraps**.

Now,

> I kept a whole plate of soup on the table for my dad, suddenly my brother came and lifted the plate and just licked the soup and saying that tasted *disgusting* he put it back on the table and ran away. He is just a mischievous boy.

**My brother made the soup _______.**

What should I put in the blank?

Can it be: **tested**?

Can i say the *remaining soup* to be **scraps** as it was just licked and looks intact?

Comment: Wouldn't you eat some food your own brother had licked? Also, how do you lick soup? soup and scraps have zero to do with each other, really. scraps are solid, not liquid.

Answer (score 2):

The word "scraps" when referring to food usually indicates solid portions, and also implies that only a relatively small amount remains of an earlier, larger meal. I would not use it in the circumstances described in the question. You could say that the soup was "unusable" if you want to indicate that because he licked it nit could not be served.

Comment: In many languages there are adjectives to describe it. So English is also supposed to have one. Could you help me find out, if it has any?

Answer (score 1):

In a food context scraps means a small amount of food.

[Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrap)

> scraps plural : fragments of discarded or leftover food

I would reorder the sentence you have provided as;

My brother *ruined* the food.

If you want to retain the word order, then you have options like;

My brother made the food *inedible*
My brother made the food *tainted*

Tainted sounds similar to tested. The word you've used in the question. Although again I'd re-order the words as;

My brother tainted the food.

[Tainted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tainted) means;

> a : contaminated by or as if by dirt, impurities, or harmful organisms

Just to be extra confusing in certain parts of the UK [scraps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scraps_(batter)) means the small pieces of batter that break off a battered fish when it is cooked.

Comment: made the food tainted is not great. Also, one would not say one's own brother tainted food because he licked it. tainted means rotten or bad due to bacteria or something like that.

Comment: @Lambie tainted means contaminated, not necessarily rotten. It is right there in the definition. It can be a very tiny amount. In a non food context a tin of paint can be tainted with a few drops of another colour, it doesn't have to make it change colour, just remove its purity.

Comment: We just wouldn't say "My brother tainted the food." in this context. A thing taints food, not a person.

Comment: @Lambie an exact google search for ["who tainted the"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBGB843GB843&sxsrf=ACYBGNRvUpbNzHFhDZzeZ5CLi92zvwQ5cw%3A1569330235046&ei=OxSKXeC4AsmRkwXYgrSQBw&q=%22Who+tainted+the%22&oq=%22Who+tainted+the%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13l10.3127.6136..6449...0.2..0.88.161.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.1h540e6isUI&ved=0ahUKEwigwsfZwunkAhXJyKQKHVgBDXIQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) which I would consider a generalised form of a person tainting a thing, reveals that amongst others the New York Times and the BBC do say a person can taint a thing.

Comment: In cooking context in a restaurant, you might say: **The cook tainted the batch of soup** because he licked the ladle". I can think of no context where one might say: My brother made the soup tainted (poor English) or My brother tainted the soup (good English,poor semantics) unless that brother worked in that kitchen.

Comment: @Lambie the "My brother made the soup tainted" I agree is poor English, I merely stated it like that initially to fit into the fill in the blank style of the question. I don't see how there is a difference between "My Brother" and "The Cook" both are common nouns naming a person. I'm happy to be corrected though. Whether the soup is on my table at home, or somewhere in a restaurant makes no difference to how the content of that bowl is described.